# How to reset user's domain policies

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I am testing a AD environment with one Domain Controller and some clients.
My user has many problems. I am member of "**domain admins, domain users and administrators**" groups and in I cannot resolve  these 2 problems:

- The tiles of the start menu are all with a "**download arrow**" that tells me an awesome app is coming. Moreover, if I delete all the tiles, when I restart the pc the tiles comes back and the entry of the start menu, like "**access 2016, word 2016 etc**" are always "**NEW**"!
- When I try to run `gpedit.msc` I see a red box tells me that i have no  permission to run it and contact my sys admin.

There are not any policy enabled on the domain.
How to verify this, or reset the default policies for the users? 
The client is a Windows 10 last release. I try to create a new local users andd the start menu is working and saves the state after reboot, so is related to te domain/ad!

AFTER SOME TESTS
Seems that the problem is not DOMAIN related. I log off the computer from the domain and create a new user. I cannot run gpedit or computer management since app is blocked. The start menu save states is working tho.

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to AD at all. What if you create a new local account on the computer, disconnect your computer from the network and then log on with the new local account? It seems like what you're getting is marketing links from Microsoft encouraging you to install Microsoft Office products.

Comment: I don't think is the correct thought. Myabe I was not clear (sorry for my english). The tiles with the download arrow are mostly all the games installed by default in windows 10. The fact that entries menu are "new" are not related to office only. It's like it load a "state" of the menu immediately after I have installed these apps. With a new local user, the start menu is working well.

Answer (score 1):

> There are not any policy enabled on the domain.

That's not strictly true. There is always at least one Group Policy Object linked to the Domain root by default (Default Domain Policy), but there are no User Configuration settings configured by default.

If you want to verify that the settings in quesiton are not being applied as a result of Group Policy then create an OU and move your computer account and user account to this OU, then block GPO inheritance on this OU and reboot the computer. Then log on and see if that changed anything.

https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/group-policy/cleaning-group-policy-when-removing-a-machine-from-the-domain/

Comment: Ok. I will try. What about the fact I cannot run gpesedit.msc or computer management, or all admin app, on my computer and I am domain admin?

Comment: see the update of the question